# one week training; in the next month; course vs training; right usage;

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

Is it right sentence:

> Firm is planning to send me to London for one week training in the next month.

"for one week training": I mean that duration of training is one week.

Also is there is really difference between "training" and "course" in terms of education?

Thanks

Comment: *"...for **a** one-week training..."* - rest is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maulik almost got it all correct, except it should be "a one-week training", the two words should be joined as a compound noun modifier.

A course seems to suggest the interaction between trainers and trainee takes the form of lecture, and is classroom based.

A training seems to cover that, and mamy other possibilities.

Comment: It should be 'a one-week training' as one begins with a consonant sound.

Comment: Oh thx, error corrected